# Java - instanceof for superclass

Tags: java, inheritance, instanceof

Let's say I have two classes:

```
public Class1 {
/* class body*/
}

public Class2 extends Class1 {
 public Class2 (int var1, int var2) {
 super(var11, var2); 
 }
}
```

Now I need to determine which class object I have. In this case, how can I determine if I have `Class1` or `Class2` object?

```
Object var1 = new Class1(1,2);
Object var2 = new Class2(1,2);

var2 instanceof Class2; /*true*/
var2 instanceof Class1 /*true*/
```

In both cases, `instanceof` will return true.

Comment: use getClass(); that returns the type you need

Comment: someObject.getClass() returns the class of an object. Note however that you should almost never have to do that. Use polymorphism.

Comment: When you say "class object", do you mean an instance of one of these classes, or a reference to one of these classes?

Comment: Also note that someObject instanceof Class2 will definitely not return true if the object is not an instance of Class2.

Comment: I mean instance of Class2 or Class1. Below answers are good, but why down vote?

Comment: Sorry I was not specific. Both are Objects, not direct instances. Now I need to determine actual object type

Comment: @user1209216 what do you mean 'not direct instances'? the downvote is most likely due to little effort to find the solution yourself. Don't know for sure, though, since I didn't downvote

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Tell us what you *really* need, not a vague issue which you don't seem to be sure about.

Comment: Question updated

Answer (score 4):

You could use `equals`:

```
if (this.getClass().equals(Class1.class) {
    // Do something...
}
```

Comment: the Class class doesn't override equals, so it might be better to compare using ==

Comment: @Stultuske May I ask why you think so? The two options are equivalent when `equals` isn't overridden.

Comment: @Slaw for one, if equals isn't overridden, it will execute the == comparison. secondly, use .equals(..) and someone not knowing that there is no implementation for equals might believe there is, and might make assumptions of the implementation

Comment: @Stultuske I always assume `equals()` would give me the correct result, if it is implemented by the core API. Anyway, `Class` class is `final`, and `Object.getClass()` is also `final native`, it really won't break unless you messed with reflections.

Comment: @Jai who's talking about anything breaking? I'm talking about situations where (unexperienced) developers having to maintain code might have wrong expectations. For instance "will the equals compare the entire path, including package, or only the name", ... which is, after all, possible when there is an implementation of equals. Calling a static method through an instance is also possible, and will also yield the right result, yet still it's not recommended to do so

Answer (score 1):

Test if it isn't an instance of the subclass:

```
   object instanceof Superclass
&& !(object instanceof Subclass)
```

Or, use an if/else chain:

```
if (object instanceof Subclass) {
  // Do something.
} else if (object instanceof Superclass) {
  // Do something else.
}
```

The choice depends upon what you're actually trying to use this for.

Comment: That would become messy if your class has a lot of subclasses :)

Comment: Indeed, this is what I want to avoid

Comment: @user1209216 can you be more specific as to what "this" is in the context of wanting to avoid? Wanting to know the class of an object is in and of itself something you should try to avoid as mentioned by JBNizet.

Comment: I have a lot of subclasses, so this approach will be messy.